# How to connect multiple signal wires to a single output?

Tags: diodes, automotive

Please forgive me if I've messed up some terminology somewhere. I've taken entry level electronics classes in college and played around with run of the mill microelectronics stuff, but please assume I know nothing.

The issue I'm dealing with is that I installed an aftermarket radio into my car that requires a connection to the emergency brake indicator. I also have an e-brake bypass that I'd like to install. The bypass fakes the e-brake signal to allow certain radio functions to be available without the e-brake actually being engaged. I'd like to keep both the existing e-brake wire and the bypass wire connected, but the issue is that when both the bypass and e-brake connection are fed together into the radio then the bypass indicates to the car that the e-brake is engaged even though it isn't.

I'm familiar with using blocking diodes to separate 3.3V/5V inputs on 3.3V/5V systems, but the e-brake uses a ground connection to signal that it is engaged. Would diodes work in this situation as well?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this situation, but it does sound as though diodes work fine here. I gather by "indicates to the car" that you mean "indicates to the computer and/or displays on a panel" and that you don't want that when the bypass is active. Is that about it?

Comment: Who comes up with these ideas?  This question would best be answered by your vehicle manufacturer.  Giving advice on how to bypass the e-brake is wrong.

Comment: @jonk That's it. The bypass, when powered on after starting the car, will connect the radio e-brake indicator to ground so that it is faking the e-brake being pulled. However, when connecting the actual e-brake indicator up to the radio the bypass indicates to the car as well as the radio that the e-brake is pulled. In my head, the curveball is that the e-brake indicator is signaled by a ground connection. Judging by your comment I'm assuming that using a couple of diodes would still work in this situation?

Comment: @Misunderstood The aftermarket radio is extremely restrictive in what it allows you to do while driving. For example, without the bypass we would have to stop the car and engage the e-brake if my wife is riding with me and wants to switch the bluetooth connection from my phone to hers so that she can stream music to the radio. I get that it's a safety issue, but I think in this particular instance they've gone a bit too far and prohibited regular, everyday tasks from being completed efficiently and safely.

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood.  You are right that is ridiculous.  But tying the brake into the radio was the idea I was referring to.  So the original "who comes up with  these ideas" still holds.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for clarifying. I'm sure there's some regulation or lawyers somewhere that required the ridiculous restrictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the following is just what you expected:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO4wgb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The brake switch will be attached as usual to the computer/whatever that does its normal stuff. But you will hook up a diode to that node/line so that you have separate access to the signal for the radio through \$D_1\$. But \$D_1\$ also keeps the computer from "seeing" your bypass switch. The radio's EBRAKE signal can see either switch condition, but the car's computer can only see the EBRAKE switch condition.

It is basically a "wire OR" arrangement using diodes. Very easy to understand and apply. You might be able to eliminate \$D_2\$. But I'd keep it in.

If the diodes drop too much voltage, you could consider using Schottky (or hot-carrier) diodes for a lower voltage drop across them. Or you could even go transistorized, I suppose. But the diodes will probably be fine.

Comment: @BrianHasden Thanks for the kind words and let me know how it works out, if willing.